# Is there something in WPF similar to Style.BasedOn for DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

At the moment, I have two very large DataTemplate objects to display two sets of items in two ListBoxes. The DataTemplates are referenced in the ContentTemplate property in two Styles that are set in the ItemContainerStyle properties of the two ListBoxes. The items are of the same type and the DataTemplates are identical except for the following control:

From DataTemplate1

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="2" Text="{Binding RemainingTime.TotalHours,
Converter={StaticResource DoubleToIntegerConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:#00}}" />
```

From DataTemplate2

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="2" Text="{Binding ElapsedTime.TotalHours,
Converter={StaticResource DoubleToIntegerConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:#00}}" />
```

Is there some way to avoid duplicating the whole Dataemplate but still have this one difference in the text binding of this TextBlock in the second template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this from another post (by Liz). Basically, you can put all common controls into one DataTemplate and then create two more DataTemplates that each use the first one as a ContentTemplate in a ContentPresenter. Then, you can add different controls into one or both of the latter DataTemplates. Liz provided a code example.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate"> 
  <!-- show all the properties of the user class here --> 
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:User}"> 
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}"/> 
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Author}"> 
  <StackPanel> 
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserTemplate}"/> 
    <!-- show all the additional Author properties here --> 
  </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks once again Liz.

Answer (score 1):

I've already asked this question here once and unfortunately there isn't.
but in this specific situation you can move the fontsize,foreground,horizontalalignment..etc to a style (lets say textstyle2) that based on your current textstyle.

Comment: The only thing that I want to change is the binding on the Text property and I don't think that I can change that in a style, can I?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no inheritance for `DataTemplate`. If you think about, how would you override a part of a `DataTemplate`?

**Solution:** Use another `Style` to capture the common properties between the two templates. You can scope it in the same `Resources` block if it only place you need it. It is much cleaner or more WPF way of doing things.

Comment: The DataTemplate is two or three hundred lines long with dozens of controls in numerous Grids. It's all common except this one line. How can I capture all of that in a Style?

Comment: You cannot capture that in a Style. I think you need to look at how you have designed the `DataTemplate` - perhaps break it into smaller pieces (think re-use) and use triggers to modify properties when conditions change. I would avoid creating a custom control if possible.

Comment: If when you say 'break it into smaller pieces', you mean put gradients, effects, etc. into the resources and just reference them from the DataTemplate controls, I already am doing this. There are just a lot of controls and binding in them. If that's not what you meant, then please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Dennis suggested, you can always create a custom control that you just stick inside your DataTemplate and re-style that control instead of the DataTemplate.